# Activate Content Organizer feature from code

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, feature, feature-activation, drop-off-library

how to activate **content organizer** feature from c# code or by powershell script.
I want to activate this feature on my subsite from my code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell:

```
if ((Get-PSSnapin -Name Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null)
{
    Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
}

$DocumentRoutingFeatureId = "7ad5272a-2694-4349-953e-ea5ef290e97c"
Enable-SPFeature -Identity $DocumentRoutingFeatureId -Url $url -ErrorAction Stop
```

where `$url` corresponds to Url of web, since the scope of this feature is **Web**

Btw, you could find the summary table with information about features (Display Name,Title,ID,Scope) available in SharePoint 2010 in post [Features and their GUID’s in SP2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mcsnoiwb/archive/2010/01/07/features-and-their-guid-s-in-sp2010.aspx)