# How do I determine a dependent hidden Site Collection feature?

Tags: feature-activation, content-organizer

When attempting to activate the Content Organizer feature for a site collection (`Site Settings > Manage Site Features > Content Organizer > Activate`) an error indicating that this feature is dependent on a underlying feature of a specific guid.  How do I go about determining the dependent feature?

`The Site scoped feature being activated has a dependency on hidden Site Collection scoped feature 'FeatureDefinition/0c8a9a47-22a9-4798-82f1-00e62a96006e' (ID: '0c8a9a47-22a9-4798-82f1-00e62a96006e'). Hidden features cannot be auto-activated across scopes. There may be one or more visible Site Collection scoped features that auto-activate the dependent hidden feature.`

A first pass through ULS I cannot gain insight.

I've also looked at the following SO question ([Activate Content Organizer feature from code](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/76219/activate-content-organizer-feature-from-code)) and MSDN forum post (https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/8f968fa4-dcff-42e7-bd12-ae715c0df880/i-cannot-activate-content-organizer-feature-on-sharepoint-2010?forum=sharepointadminprevious) to no avail.

Comment: By the way, another way to avoid this error is to activate publishing features first. https://support.office.com/article/enable-publishing-features-479677a6-8b33-4ac7-907d-071c1c7e4518

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to put that feature ID in Google, you'll end up on this page:

https://absolute-sharepoint.com/2012/06/sharepoint-2010-features-names-and-their-guid-for-powershell.html

This feature is:

Name: DocumentRoutingResources
Title: Document Routing Resources
ID: 0c8a9a47-22a9-4798-82f1-00e62a96006e
Scope: Site

Comment: i'm surprised MSDN doesn't have this guid to feature mapping in their documentation and was up to a blogger to compile